# Program to input 10 numbers, count and output the positive and negative numbers in python (3.7.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you create a variable that would define a positive number and a negative number and then use it to relate to this specific list of numbers
Side note: I do not have to categorize 0 in this code

So far all I've managed to do is figure out the positive or negative number in a list, not both:

```
num = [ int(input("enter number: ")) for x in range (10) ]


for x in num:
    if num>0:
        print("num is positive")
```

However as expected this would substitute the number that is positive with this string and would not define which number is positive. I'm also not sure how to use a count for the negative and positive number.

Answer (score 1):

Counting how many positive/negative numbers you have is very easy in this case:

```
n_positive = n_negative = 0
for n in num:
    if n > 0:
        n_positive = n_positive + 1
    elif n < 0:
        n_negative = n_negative + 1
```

If you also want to know which number is positive/negative:

```
n_positive = n_negative = 0
for n in num:
    if n > 0:
        n_positive = n_positive + 1
        print(n, 'is positive')
    elif n < 0:
        n_negative = n_negative + 1
        print(n, 'is negative')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `else` and `elif` (means else-if) keyword like this:

```
num = [ int(input("enter number: ")) for x in range (10) ]


for x in num:
    if num>0:
        print("num is positive")
    elif num == 0:
        print("number is zero")
    else:
        print("number is negative")
```